# Стоит ли использовать формы при верстке сайтов?

Tags: forms, html, css

Здравствуйте.

Возникла такая ситуация. Сейчас читаю книгу: "HTML5 и CSS3. Веб-разработка по стандартам нового поколения", автор Брайан Хоган. В этой книге много чего делается с помощью форм (<form>). А не устарел ли этот метод посторения сайтов/страничек с помощью форм? Ибо уже после просмотра множества новых сайтов, формы почти не используются. И посоветуйте, пожалуйста, книги по html5+css3.

Спасибо.

Comment: А что собственно плохого в теге <form>?

Comment: Ну просто после появления новшеств в языке html, не устарел ли этот тэг? И если так, как его заменяют?

Comment: Вопрос звучит видимо от верстальщика...

Comment: От начинающего.

Comment: @vova666 - там "быть может" стоит начать свой путь с каких-то "земных" вещей? Или вы думаете что вы сможете писать супер крутые приложения после того как прочтете пару "крутых" книг?( кстати, ИМХО, книга Г )

Тег не устарел и не устареет (откуда у вас вообще взялась столь бредовая мысль?), его функционал заменяют клиентским кодом (а не каким-то волшебным тегом). Хотя не удивлюсь если Вы и с JS то не знакомы ни грамма.

Comment: С чего Вы взяли что после прочтения книги буду писать супер мега сайты? И то что Js не знаком а? Делаете такие выводы даже ничего не зная. А книга действительно Г

Comment: Один неадекват от вас. Не о чем с вами разговаривать. И если не нравится вопрос, проигнорируйте его, ибо показываете свою глупость

Comment: не глупость а агресивность, в этом я поддержу автору вопроса. Сразу же видно что он начинающий. уверен, похожими вопросами задаются многие из нас, видимо кое-кто забыл что сам был таким же (или даже есть, но не хочет себе в этом признаватся)

Answer (score 10):

Форма — это набор полей и способ передать их на сервер. Метод, замечу, универсальный, работающий везде. Тег как deprecated не объявлялся, и, более того, в [HTML5](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/forms.html) шло развитие форм. Там же, [про `<input>` пишут](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-input-element.html), что «the input element represents a typed data field, usually with a form control to allow the user to edit the data.»

Дальше, если хочется гламура, можно навесить (progressive enhancement, ага) поверх формы, переопределив поведение браузера, хоть AJAX, хоть вебсокеты, хоть черта в ступе. Формам это никак не мешает, это их только улучшает.

Вот если вести речь не о веб-сайте, а веб-приложении, то ситуация несколько меняется. Но там и HTML несколько моветон, никто непосредственно на нем в веб-приложениях давно ничего не делает — он, в чистом виде, для них все еще плохо пригоден. Там царствуют специальные библиотеки, фреймворки и DSL'и для описания пользовательских интерфейсов. ExtJS, Sproutcore, YUI, GWT, ...

Comment: А что именно можно называть веб-приложением? Игры?

Comment: @Construct: Игры, web-почту, онлайн-IDE, RSS-читалки и многое другое. Есть много мнений, я выскажу свое. Суть не в содержимом, а в устройстве, структуре. Сайт — это, первично, отдельные (пусть даже и связанные одной темой и оформлением), связанные между собой гиперссылками, страницы-документы с информацией для чтения, а приложение — целостный интерфейс с функционалом (но не сайт). При этом все сложно и нечетко. Частичные обновления страниц AJAX'ом еще не делают из сайта приложения, а документы в Google Docs еще не делают их сайтом.